# How to disable Button if EditText is empty ?

Tags: android, button

I have an EditText and a Button in my application.

When the button is clicked,the text entered in the EditText is added to a ListView.

I want to disable the Button if the EditText is empty.How to do this ?

This is my code for button click

```
ImageButton imb=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
            imb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) 
             { 
                 EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);

                  String str = et.getText().toString();
                  web1.add(str);
                  Toast.makeText(ShoutSingleProgram.this, "You entered...."+str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  et.setText("");

                    }
            });
            }
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
    editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

           if(s.toString().trim().length()==0){
                button.setEnabled(false);
              } else {
                button.setEnabled(true);
              }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: `onTextChanged` isn't called if user doesn't type something in edit. How I can handle it except handling in `onClick`?

Comment: You might wanna set the button to false in the first place

Answer (score 9):

Use `TextChangedListener` and initially disable `ImageButton` in onCreate().

Try this

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton imb;
EditText et;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);

    imb.setEnabled(false); // set button disable initially

    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (s.toString().equals("")) {
                imb.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                imb.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Simple just check the condition in onCreate

```
if (et.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
  button.setEnabled(false);
}
else{
button.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### Here's a super simple answer in Kotlin.

Just replace 'EditText' and 'Button' with your own.

```
Button.isEnabled = false
        EditText.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
            override fun onTextChanged(s:CharSequence, start:Int, before:Int, count:Int) {
                Button.isEnabled = s.toString().trim{ it <= ' ' }.isNotEmpty()
            }
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s:CharSequence, start:Int, count:Int,
                                           after:Int) {
            }
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
            }
        })
```

For Multiple EditTexts go

```
Button.isEnabled = false
            val editTexts = listOf(editText1, editText2, editText3, editText4, editText5, editText6)
for (editText in editTexts) {
            editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                var et1 = editText1.text.toString().trim()
                var et2 = editText2.text.toString().trim()
                var et3 = editText3.text.toString().trim()
                var et4 = editText4.text.toString().trim()
                var et5 = editText5.text.toString().trim()
                var et6 = editText6.text.toString().trim()

                computeBtn.isEnabled = et1.isNotEmpty()
                        && et2.isNotEmpty()
                        && et3.isNotEmpty()
                        && et4.isNotEmpty()
                        && et5.isNotEmpty()
                        && et6.isNotEmpty()
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(
                s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(
                s: Editable) {
            }
        })
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

## *Easy Solution*

This is very easy to implement in [Data-Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/). I hope you are aware of it at this time. You can manage Button with EditText via only XML.

```
android:enabled="@{etName.text.length() > 0 &amp;&amp; etPassword.text.length() > 5}"
```

Which is equivalent to

```
button.setEnabled(etName.getText().length() > 0 && etPassword.getText().length() > 5 );
```

- Here `&amp;` is [HTML entity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612818/6891563) which denotes to **`&`**. There can be any operator like &.
- `etName` & `etPassword` are EditTexts ids.

**Complete XML -**

```
<LinearLayout
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        />

    <Button
        android:enabled="@{etName.text.length() > 5 &amp;&amp; etPassword.text.length() > 5}"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does the button gets enabled again just after those conditions are met? if not, I think your answer is eighter useless or irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

I used `TextUtils` for a concise solution:

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            button.setEnabled(!TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString().trim()));
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an object oriented solution and reuse your code

```
public abstract class EmptyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher
{
    public abstract void onEmptyField();

    public abstract void onFilledField();

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        if (s.toString().trim().length() == 0)
        {
            onEmptyField();
        } else
        {
            onFilledField();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {

    }



    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {

    }

}
```

so you can use it just doing

```
textView.addTextChangedListener(new EmptyTextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void onEmptyField()
            {
                button.setEnabled(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFilledField()
            {
                button.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a TextWatcher to your EditText, so that when you change the text inside it, you Button enables or disables itself.

Answer (score 1):

Initally in `onCreate()` disable the button.
Then add a `addTextChangedListener`to the edit text. within that check the edittext length and disable if it is 0 or otherwise enable it

Answer (score 0):

on Oncreate() , before button click  you should check the condition as,

```
   ImageButton imb=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
   EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
   if(et.getText().toString().equals("")
   {
   imb.setEnabled(false);
   }

   imb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) 
         { 
             EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);

              String str = et.getText().toString();
              web1.add(str);
              Toast.makeText(ShoutSingleProgram.this, "You entered...."+str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
              et.setText("");

                }
        });
```

Comment: OP needs a textWatcher.

Answer (score 0):

When you want  to disable the editText there You will use below code

```
editText.setEnabled(false); 
editText.setFocusable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

you check the status of an edittext at runtime using the text watcher.
the below code counts the text length and disables if the length is zero.
use this code:

```
EditText mEditText = new EditText(this);
    mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (s.length() == 0) {
                button.setEnabled(false);
            }
                            else {
                            button.setEnabled(true);
                        }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone was wondering here is the kotlin version of the code

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
        override fun onTextChanged(s:CharSequence, start:Int, before:Int, count:Int) {
            if (s.toString().trim({ it <= ' ' }).isEmpty())
            {
                button.setEnabled(false)
            }
            else
            {
                button.setEnabled(true)
            }
        }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s:CharSequence, start:Int, count:Int,
                              after:Int) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    })
```

Comment: if i'm right  `s.toString().trim({ it <= ' ' }).isEmpty()` is the same as `s.isBlank()`.

in that case onTextChanged can be simplified to:
`button.isEnabled = s.isBlank()`

Answer (score 0):

Same as the top accepted answer, but simplified. Remember to wrap the condition in `()` so it uses the boolean.

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
         button.setEnabled((s.toString().trim().length()>0));     
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
EditText TextBox1, TextBox2;
Button btn;

 //Code of onCreate() method is start here:
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextBox1 = findViewById(R.id.TextBox1);
    TextBox2 = findViewById(R.id.TextBox2);

    TextBox1.addTextChangedListener(CheckEmptyTxtBoxes);
    TextBox2.addTextChangedListener(CheckEmptyTxtBoxes);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
  }

    //Code of TechWatcher listener start here:
    private TextWatcher CheckEmptyTxtBoxes = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        try {
            String txtbox1 = TextBox1.getText().toString().trim();
            String txtbox2 = TextBox2.getText().toString().trim();
            if (!txtbox1.isEmpty() && !txtbox2.isEmpty()) {
                btn.setEnabled(true);
                btn.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#0307F4")));
            } else {
                btn.setEnabled(false);
                btn.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#8486FB")));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OnTextChanged method error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
};
```

Comment: Please note that linking to your own content when it's not relevant to the question can be considered spam on this site. You're welcome to advertise your content in your profile page, but please refrain from doing so in questions and answers on the site.