# How to use kotlin.Int in databinding?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I wrote a layout xml like below.
But the Kotlin compiler says `Cannot resolve symbol 'Int'`

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout ...>
  <data>
    <import type="androidx.databinding.ObservableArrayMap" />
    <variable
      name="myList"
      type="ObservableArrayMap&lt;Int,String&gt;" />
  </data>

<!-- ...... -->    

</layout>
```

Is it possible to use kotlin builtins in android databinding xml?

Comment: Because you can't use `key` as `Int`. Use `ObservableArrayMap&lt;String,String&gt;`

Comment: Use Integer instead of Int.

Comment: @karandeepsingh Yeah. If I use Integer instead of Int, it's fine. I thought the kotlin compiled the databinding xml to kotlin and then to java. But it seems it doesn't..

Answer (score 7):

- Use java `Integer` instead of kotlin `Int`.
- You can not use characters <,> etc in XML. So use [HTML entities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612818/6891563).

like

```
ObservableArrayMap&lt;Integer,String&gt;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add data binding simple way.

**Configure your app to use the data binding:**

Open the app/build.gradle, Then you have to add these line of code inside the android tags in gradle and sync project

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

**Layout and Binding Expression in Data Binding:**

Open the layout (XML) file activity_main and replace the root with layout tag and place all tags inside to layout tags.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout>

<layout>
```

**Replace the traditional setContentView() to DataBindingUtil.setContentView() in Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ActivityMainBinding binding;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
   }
}
```

Let’s us see **how to data bind with Views and Widget using data binding**

```
 binding.tvName.setText("Monika Sharma");
 binding.tvAddress.setText("251 mansarovar Jaipur | India ");
 binding.tvFollowers.setText("240K");
 binding.tvfollowing.setText("324K");
```