# How to add OR operator in XML?

Tags: android, xml, data-binding, operator-keyword, android-databinding

I have found some resources about how to implement `AND`, `less than` and `greater than` operator in XML for Android data-binding.

`&` -> `&amp;`

`<` -> `&lt;`

`>` -> `&gt;`

However, how to add `OR` operator? I cannot find the related information in Android official documentation.

I have visited these sites

[StackOverflow --- android databinding using "&&" logical operator - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152824/android-databinding-using-logical-operator)

[StackOverflow --- android-databinding-using-logical-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152824/android-databinding-using-logical-operator)

[Escape And(&&) Operator In Android Data Binding](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/using-logical-operator-in-android-data-binding/)

My expected result:

````
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="@{viewModel.fooBoolOne ||  viewModel.fooBoolTwo ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>```
````

Comment: Those are XML entity escape codes, and have nothing to do with operators.

Comment: If the operator in question is "||", then it doesn't need to be escaped in XML, it can be written as is.

Comment: It should be working as it is.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `||` operator in your xml without any changes.

Example :-

```
10 || 12
```