# How to do enable a button and change its colour when textfield has some value?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have tried many answers already given to this, but nothing seems to work properly. And the answers are only for changing state of the button, not colour and text. What am I missing?

I am a very VERY new learner to both Android and programming. And this is my first question on Stack Overflow. Hope it's as per guidelines.

I have a login page which looks like below (img1) [disabled][1]. If textfield has any value, the button should get enabled (img2) [enabled][2]. The Java and XML files are given below.

```
package io.kaapi.kaapimobileassistant.Activities;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.UnderlineSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.TextView;
import io.kaapi.kaapimobileassistant.Misc.StorageManager;
import io.kaapi.kaapimobileassistant.R;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final static String TAG = "LoginActivity";
private Button login_button;
private TextInputLayout login_activation_layout;
private EditText login_activation_code;
private LinearLayout login_signup;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    login_activation_layout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.login_acitivation_layout);
    login_activation_code = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_activation_code);
    login_signup = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.login_signup);

    login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Login pressed");
            String activation_code_layout = login_activation_layout.getEditText().getText().toString();
            Log.v(TAG, "Layout "+activation_code_layout);
            String activation_code = login_activation_code.getText().toString();
            Log.v(TAG, "Code "+activation_code);
            if(activation_code.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                Log.v(TAG, "It's blank");
                login_activation_layout.setError("Please enter an activation code");
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "Call login API, validate and show errors or login");
                //StorageManager.write(LoginActivity.this, null, "client_domain", "http://ankit50.kaapi.io");
                //StorageManager.write(LoginActivity.this, null, "client_logo", "http://cdn.kaapi.io/static");
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
            }
        }
    });

    login_activation_code.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            enableSubmitIfReady();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        public void enableSubmitIfReady() {

            Button login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

            if(login_activation_code.toString().trim().length()==0){
                login_button.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                login_button.setEnabled(true);

            }
        }
    });



    login_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://business.kaapi.io");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

The XML file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="io.kaapi.kaapimobileassistant.Activities.LoginActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="71dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="71dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    android:src="@drawable/kaapi_logo_login"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTitle"
    android:text="Activate Mobile Assistant"
    android:textSize="24sp" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="@color/colorText"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_info_outline_black_24dp"/>

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="The code was sent to you in sign up email and your web dashboard." />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_acitivation_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_activation_code"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:hint="Activation code"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
    android:text="Activate"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="New to Kaapi?  " />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_signup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:text="Sign up first"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The way you have formulated your question (and its title) currently its off-topic ("Why isn't my code working?"). Please edit it. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Hi @Shaishav - I did check that and made sure that question "_must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself._" as per the guidelines. My desired behaviour and specific problem is the button color change in the java logic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Button if EditText is empty ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680106/how-to-disable-button-if-edittext-is-empty)

Comment: @ShaishavJogani I did see that query, but the same does not answer for different button colours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
public void enableSubmitIfReady() {

        Button login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        if(login_activation_code.toString().trim().length()==0){
            login_button.setClickable(false);
            login_button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.holo_light_green));// change color here so it's look like button disable
        } else {
            login_button.setClickable(true);
            login_button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.holo_dark_green));
        }
    }
```

Comment: no it's color from my  color.xml you can use any color you want .

Comment: Update: I was able to make it work (you are awesome btw!), but with a small hitch. The button if once changes to active colour, remains like so always. If I remove all text from the field, it should go back to disabled state. Which is not happening

Comment: Yes, it is on onTextchanged. Before and aftertextchanged are empty methods in my code.

Comment: you are calling it from method don't do that put condition only in onTextChanged  method