# How to disable button when listView is empty?

Tags: android, listview

I am developing an android app and have a problem: my main activity contains a listview and a button and I need to disable the button when the listview is empty.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680106/how-to-disable-button-if-edittext-is-empty) but the listview doesn't have `addTextChangedListener`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the adapter `.registerDataSetObserver()` method which is triggered every time the data of the `ListView` is changed.

Here is a simple example of what you need to achieve

**How it looks like**

[image]

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_disable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="Disabled" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_add_data"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_remove_data"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Remove" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Behaviour

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button btnDisabled = findViewById(R.id.btn_disable);
        Button btnRemoveData = findViewById(R.id.btn_remove_data);
        Button btnAddData = findViewById(R.id.btn_add_data);
        final ListView mList = findViewById(R.id.listview);

        final List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);

        mList.setAdapter(adapter);

        btnAddData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                data.add("Data");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();
                if (mList.getAdapter().isEmpty())
                    btnDisabled.setEnabled(false);
                else
                    btnDisabled.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        btnRemoveData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!data.isEmpty())
                    data.remove(data.size() - 1);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. Curiously, is there a way to disable the button the first time the list is empty (when launching the app)?

Comment: glad for that; you may use  xml attribute android:enabled="false" or .setEnabled(false) in the very beginning of the .onCreate() method

Comment: I understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to hide the button, then you can use `button.setvisiblity(View.GONE)` or else If you want to just disable the button then you can setAlpha  and in button onClick listner you can restrict the action's if list view is empty.

Comment: I implemented the OnClickListener, but this not work in the first moment when my listview is empty. There is a way this work in the first moment?